# Generate datalist number of times

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, datalist

I have one textbox on page and DataList.
Now, When User enters any integer number in textbox and click on button then same datalist will be generate for number of times.
For i.e. If user enteres 5 then datalist will generate 5 times. datalist contains same data.
I am not getting any idea about how to do this ? Please help me to solve this problem.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server"> -> 3
```

Then It generates Datalist as :

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl" runat="server"></asp:DataList>
<asp:DataList ID="dl" runat="server"></asp:DataList>
<asp:DataList ID="dl" runat="server"></asp:DataList>
```

So, I want copy of `DataList` 5 times if user enters for example 5.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt "en User enters any integer number in textbox and click on button then same datalist will be generate for number of times. am not getting any idea about how to do this ?" - he wants to generate a data list (as in his bottom code example) with a number of items that is equal to a number the user entered in a text box.

Comment: this will help,http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/370784/How-To-Create-Dynamically-datalist

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, yes rite. you can say that same copy of datalist number of times user enter number in textbox.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, I am not getting any idea about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

use repeater, each item of which is DataList

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <HeaderTemplate>
         <table>
      </HeaderTemplate>

      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <asp:DataList ID="dl" runat="server" DataSource = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyCollectionProperty") %>' />
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>

      <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
      </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Than when user enters for example 10, generate 10 Items, each of which contains collection of items(MyCollectionProperty property in example) that need to be shown and assign the array of 10 items to repeater datasource

Comment: I don't want 10 items. I want copy of Datalist 10 times if user enters for example 10.

Comment: you can keep reference from all 10 elements to same dataitem, does this make sense?

Comment: I don't have idea that's why I have posted my question here. But I want copy of data.

Comment: you don't necessarily need to copy data, no one prevents you to keep 10 samples of the same item in the array and pass to repeater

Answer (score 0):

Seems you would generate DataList dynamically.
If the DataList will contain the same data, so you can make only one data source which you familiar to.

For my sample I would use SqlDataSource as my data source and share it for other DataLists.
If you create a template for DataList (such my **dtlTemplate**), also define the `<ItemTemplate>` element, it will be simpler.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnOK_Click"/><br />

<asp:DataList Visible="false" ID="dtlTemplate" runat="server" DataKeyField="id" 
    DataSourceID="dataSource" Width="845px">
    <ItemTemplate>
       id:<asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' /><br />
       name:<asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' /><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dataSource" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

In your button click handler should be like this:

```
protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number = int.Parse(txtNumber.Text == "" ? "0" : txtNumber.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        //Create new DataList with copying ItemTemplate from dtlTemplate
        DataList dtl = new DataList();
        dtl.ID = "dtl" + i;
        dtl.ItemTemplate = dtlTemplate.ItemTemplate;

        //Add new DataList to form1 (parent control)
        form1.Controls.Add(dtl);

        //Set the same data source with dtlTemplate to new DataList
        dtl.DataSourceID = dtlTemplate.DataSourceID;
        dtl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.